# Is it okay to edit part(s) of code not yet reviewed?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-policy, editing, answer-invalidation

In [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25824/improving-my-floating-point-binary-decimal-octal-hex-converter) question of mine, the one answerer so far has only reviewed a part of my code.  However, I've made changes on *other* parts of my code, but I don't want to somehow invalidate that answer.

Would it be proper to, cautiously, edit any part(s) of the code not already reviewed?  If so, would an appropriate note in the question suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one time to revise code after receiving an answer is if advice is given in a comment.  Unlike answers, comments are temporary and do not have to remain.

If you find something yourself and would like to point it out, even if it's a bug fix, it would be better to post it as a self-answer.  [It *is* okay to review your own code;](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it is not at all discouraged.  It should still be in a review format, much like any other review you may encounter on the site.

Bearing that in mind, you should *not* post the entire updated code (even with improvements) as that could encourage reviews of that code.  This is not preferred as answers cannot be reviewed in the same way as questions, but they can still be critiqued like any other review answer.

Answer (score 11):

Cautiously editing any part might not be a good idea. Someone might have copied your code and be studying in their IDE. That is what I usually do instead of reading online. That could lead to confusion.

A note in the question might not be enough.